# Identificar a posição da primeira célula vazia

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma integração web que envia para minha planilha valores automaticamente.

Em uma de minhas colunas tenho uma URL que é concatenada com o valor de um ID da coluna ao lado. Preciso acrescentar neste valor da URL, a posição da célula ao lado conforme este exemplo:

A1: `=CONCATENAR("http://www.teste.com.br/?id=";B1)`

A fórmula precisaria identificar a posição B1 e não o valor que está em B1. Por padrão todos os valores da coluna B ficam como vazios.

Conhecem alguma forma?

#### Edit:

Seria o seguinte: `A1: www.teste.com.br/id=` e `B1: ""`

```
+----------------------+----+
|          A1          | B1 |
+----------------------+----+
| www.teste.com.br/id= |    |
+----------------------+----+
```

(não tem valor em B1, é vazio)

#### Resultado que eu pretendo obter:

`www.teste.com.br/id=B1`

O único detalhe, é que eu não posso usar uma fórmula com referência a alguma célula fixa como por exemplo `LIN(B1)` não posso usar pois quando meu código for enviar uma nova linha, não será mais `B1` e sim `B2`.

A lógica que pensei foi em encontrar na coluna B o primeiro valor vazio.

Answer (score 1):

Para obter o número da [última linha da coluna B](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-value-of-last-non-empty-cell), ou seja, retornar o valor da última linha preenchida da coluna B. A seguinte fórmula é usada: `=SEERRO(PROC(2;1/(B:B<>"");LIN(B:B));1)`

Então a fórmula final é: `=CONCATENAR("http://www.teste.com.br/?id=";"B"&SEERRO(PROC(2;1/(B:B<>"");LIN(B:B));1))`

Em que o resultado é visto no exemplo abaixo: `http://www.teste.com.br/?id=B5`

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Não é exatamente isso...

Vamos supor que eu coloque: `=CONCATENAR("http://www.teste.com.br/?id=B";LIN(B1))` 

Tem alguma forma do resultado apresentar a concatenação com o valor da célula B1 ao invés de concatenar o texto B1 ?

Comment: Me dê um exemplo do valor da célula `B1`. Do que tem na célula B1 e o que você deseja de resultado.

Comment: Seria o seguinte:

`A1: www.teste.com.br/id=` `B1: ""`(não tem valor em B1, é vazio)

Resultado que eu pretendo obter: `www.teste.com.br/id=B1`

O único detalhe, é que eu não posso usar uma fórmula com referência a alguma célula fixa como por exemplo `LIN(B1)` não posso usar pois quando meu código for enviar uma nova linha, não será mais `B1` e sim `B2`. A lógica que pensei foi em encontrar na coluna `B` o primeiro valor vazio.

Comment: @FábioJunioAlvesSousa verifique a edição.

Comment: Muito Obrigado @danieltakeshi pelo esforço em tentar me ajudar! No fim das contas a lógica que havia em identificar uma célula vazia não funcionaria na prática, pois sempre que inserir um dado na coluna ao lado, a fórmula iria identifica a próxima célula vazia mudando constantemente a referência. Eu consegui fazendo de outra forma, identificar apenas a referência da célula ao lado, fazendo desta simples forma:

`=CONCATENAR("www.teste.com.br/id=";INDIRETO("B"&LIN()))`

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa usar a [função](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/endere%C3%87o-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-endere%C3%87o-d0c26c0d-3991-446b-8de4-ab46431d4f89) `ENDEREÇO`:

```
=CONCATENAR("http://www.teste.com.br/?id=";ENDEREÇO(1,2,4))
```